# React State Updation Issue

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

My component's state is as below:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
        teamMembersOptions: [],
        selectedTeamMember: {},
    });
```

teamMembersOptions are being mapped from the redux state teamMembersList as below:

```
    const teamMembersList = useSelector(state => state.get_all_team_members.team)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (teamMembersList)
            mapTeamMembers();
    }, [teamMembersList])

    const mapTeamMembers = () => {
        const teamMembers = [];
        teamMembersList.map(member => {
            const memberObject = {
                'value': member.id,
                'label': member.first_name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + member.first_name.slice(1) + ' ' + member.last_name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + member.last_name.slice(1)
            }
            if (member.is_leader == 1) {
                memberObject.label = memberObject.label + ' (owner)'
                setState({
                    ...state,
                    selectedTeamMember: memberObject
                })
            }
            teamMembers.push(memberObject)
        })
        setState({
            ...state,
            teamMembersOptions: teamMembers
        })
    }
```

The state variables of selectedTeamMember and teamMemberOptions are not updating, it keeps consoling empty state. Whenever I console the local array of teamMembers inside mapTeamMembers function, it logs all the values successfully teamMembersList from Redux
also logs successfully that means teamMembersList and teamMembers are not empty. But the state is not updating. Why the setState statement inside mapTeamMembers function is not updating the state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of things going on here and lot of them cause renders to trigger more renders which is why you are getting unexpected output.

I have add `useMemo()` and `useCallback()` around the data and calculation method respectively, and added their return values to the dependency array for `useEffect()`. This is to avoid the `useEffect` dependencies change on every render.

Calling `setState()` within the `.map()` function doesn't feel like the right choice either as each time it is called a render might occur, even though you are halfway through the mapping operation. Instead I suggest, and opted for, using `.reduce()` on the array and returning that result which can then be used to update the state within the `useEffect` hook.

Have a look at the working code below and a sample output given the defined input from `teamMembersList`. Note: this doesn't use Redux in the example given that it more setup to prove the concept.

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    teamMembersOptions: [],
    selectedTeamMember: {}
  });

  const teamMembersList = useMemo(
    () => [
      { id: 1, first_name: "John", last_name: "Smith", is_leader: 0 },
      { id: 2, first_name: "Maggie", last_name: "Simpson", is_leader: 1 }
    ],
    []
  );

  const mapTeamMembers = useCallback(
    () =>
      teamMembersList.reduce(
        (acc, member) => {
          const memberObject = {
            value: member.id,
            label:
              member.first_name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
              member.first_name.slice(1) +
              " " +
              member.last_name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
              member.last_name.slice(1)
          };
          if (member.is_leader === 1) {
            memberObject.label = memberObject.label + " (owner)";
            acc.leader = memberObject;
          }
          acc.teamMembers.push(memberObject);
          return acc;
        },
        {
          teamMembers: [],
          leader: ""
        }
      ),
    [teamMembersList]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (teamMembersList) {
      const members = mapTeamMembers();
      setState({
        selectedTeamMember: members.leader,
        teamMembersOptions: members.teamMembers
      });
    }
  }, [teamMembersList, mapTeamMembers, setState]);

  return (
    <div>
      <pre>
        <code>{JSON.stringify(state, null, 4)}</code>
      </pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The above will render out:

```json
{
    "selectedTeamMember": {
        "value": 2,
        "label": "Maggie Simpson (owner)"
    },
    "teamMembersOptions": [
        {
            "value": 1,
            "label": "John Smith"
        },
        {
            "value": 2,
            "label": "Maggie Simpson (owner)"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd consider splitting the `state` object into individual state items but that's really up to you and how you want to handle the data.